# Add dropbox video to html web page

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf, dropbox-api

I'm trying to integrate video file (mp4) from the Dropbox Api (Java) to my spring-made web site with thymeleaf. However, I couldn't access link with the video file.
My idea is -->

```
<html>
<main>
    <h2 th:text="${videoName}"></h2>
    <video>
        <source src="*/some url from the dropbox api to visualize the video\*"/>
    </video>
    <p th:text="${videoDescription}"></p>
    ...
</main>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. I have to embed the shared file link and replace dl=0 with raw=1.

```
<html>
<main>
    <h2 th:text="${videoName}"></h2>
    <iframe th:src="${dropboxUrl}"></iframe>
    <p th:text="${videoDescription}"></p>
    ...
</main>
</html>
```

The original shared link can be received via ListSharedLinkResult.

```
ListSharedLinksResult listSharedLinksResult = dbxClientV2.sharing().listSharedLinksBuilder().withPath(dropboxPath).withDirectOnly(true).start();
String result = listSharedLinksResult.getLinks().get(0).getUrl();
```